# помогите разобраться с алгоритмом сортировки массива

Tags: javascript, html

не сортирует как положено....
ввожу:

```
5 4 7 8 3 2
```

сортированный массив выводится такой:

```
4,8,5,7,3,2
```

......голову уже очень долго ломаю....не пойму в чем причина.....нашел что в условии if где-то загвоздка....срабатывает только один раз почему-то

```
<h1>task sort array</h1>
<input id="inputArray">
<input id="button" type="button" value="sort">
<p id="exitArray">exitArray</p>
<script>

   function sortArray() {
      var inputArray = document.getElementById('inputArray').value;

      var convertArray = inputArray.split(' '),
         indexElement = 0,
         indexNextElement = indexElement + 1,
         temp = 0,
         indexIteration = 0;

     for (;indexIteration < convertArray.length - 1; indexIteration++ ) {

        for (; indexElement < convertArray.length - 1; indexElement++) {

             if (convertArray[indexElement] > convertArray[indexNextElement]) {   

                 temp = convertArray[indexElement] ;
                 convertArray[indexElement] = convertArray[indexNextElement];
                 convertArray[indexNextElement] = temp;
             }
        }
     }
     document.getElementById('exitArray').innerHTML = convertArray;
   }
button.addEventListener("click", sortArray);
</script>
```

Comment: Ну, для начала, у вас indexNextElement всегда равен 1...

Comment: И `indexElement` во внутреннем цикле, помнится, должен начинаться со значения `indexIteration`.

Comment: Darth, почему ранво 1? 

    я перед циклом присваиваю хначение iE+1 и на первой итерации равно 1, потом 2, потом 3, потом 4...

Comment: @Александр вы **перед** циклом присваиваете значение 0+1, и потом оно на любой итерации равно 1. Чтобы оно менялось, его надо каждый раз вычислять по новой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто нерабочий алгоритм у вас получился, вот и всё)

Вот так надо:)

```
<h1>task sort array</h1>
<input id="inputArray">
<input id="button" type="button" value="sort">
<p id="exitArray">exitArray</p>
<script>

   function sortArray() {
      var inputArray = document.getElementById('inputArray').value;

      var convertArray = inputArray.split(' '), // split возвращает массив строк
         indexElement = 0,
         indexNextElement = indexElement + 1,
         temp = 0,
         indexIteration = 0;
     var _tempArray =[];
     for(var i=0; i < convertArray.length; i++)
        _tempArray.push(parseInt(convertArray[i])); // массив строк преобразовываем в массив целых чисел
     convertArray = _tempArray;

     for (;indexIteration < convertArray.length - 1; indexIteration++ ) {

        for (indexElement = indexIteration + 1; indexElement < convertArray.length; indexElement++) {

             if (convertArray[indexElement] > convertArray[indexIteration]) {   

                 temp = convertArray[indexElement] ;
                 convertArray[indexElement] = convertArray[indexIteration];
                 convertArray[indexIteration] = temp;
             }
        }
     }
     document.getElementById('exitArray').innerHTML = convertArray;
   }
button.addEventListener("click", sortArray);
</script>
```

Comment: напишите хотя бы в чем ошибка

Comment: Сергей Полушин, вот я и хочу понять в ЧЕМ он получился НЕрабочим....где я и что я не учел...

Comment: @Александр, ну вы просто попробуйте написать этот массив на листочке, пошагово выполняйте свой алгоритм и записывайте изменения. Тогда вы поймете, что ваш алгоритм не сортирует, а черт знает каким образом и зачем бросает цифры туда-сюда)) Основное конечно то, что второй цикл у меня итерируется не с начала массива, а с того, на котором сейчас находится внешний(первый) цикл. Это основное, наверное.

Comment: да я весь алгоритм на листике, как раз, и написал...

Comment: Сергей Полушин, Ваш код немного неккоректно работает!
я ввожу: 5 4 1 0 -9 68 -5 -458,
выдает: 68,5,4,1,0,-9,-5,-458 !!!-9 НЕ может быть больше -5!!!

Comment: @Александр, да, действительно. Поправил свой ответ. Проблема была в том, что  split возвращает массив строк и далее, соответственно, мы сравнивали между собой не числа, а строки в лексикографическом порядке.

Comment: Сергей Полушин, спасибо Вам)

Answer (score 2):

> я вот одного не пойму зачем так все усложнять. **вот же** так можно в функциональщине

функция компаратор сортировки

```
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

и сама функция сортировки

```
arr.sort(compareNumbers)
```

***И ВСЕ***

```js
 function sortArray() {
      var inputArray = document.getElementById('inputArray').value;

      var arr = inputArray.split(' '); // split возвращает массив строк
     
     const convertArray = arr.sort(compareNumbers);
     
     document.getElementById('exitArray').innerHTML = convertArray;
 }

button.addEventListener("click", sortArray);

function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

```html
<h1>task sort array</h1>
<input id="inputArray">
<input id="button" type="button" value="sort">
<p id="exitArray">exitArray</p>
```